# calculate the total number of occurrence of a list of keyword in a string column

Tags: r

I have a data frame  `df` which contains a column named `strings`. The values in this column are some sentences.

For example:

```
id    strings
1     "I like you"
2     "I like you, too."
3     "I like you so much
4     "I like you very much"
5     "I don't like you"
```

Now, I have a list of keyword,

```
["I", "don't", "like", "you"]
```

How can I make another data frame which stores the total number of occurrence of each keyword in the column of previous data frame.

```
keyword      frequency
  I               5
  don't           1
  like            5
  you             5
```

I am think about to use for loop to iterate the string list and make a column for each keyword in original data frame. Then count the number of occurrence in each row, finally sum the columns up. However, since the list of keyword is quite big, it is really inefficient to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `sapply` on list of `keywords` and count the number of rows where the `keywords` occur using `grepl`.

```
keywords <- c("I", "don't", "like", "you")
stack(sapply(keywords, function(x) sum(grepl(paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"), df$strings))))

#  values   ind
#1      5     I
#2      1 don't
#3      5  like
#4      5   you
```

Or a `tidyverse` way would be

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(keywords) %>%
  mutate(Frequency = map_int(keywords, ~ 
                           sum(grepl(paste0("\\b", ., "\\b"), df$strings))))
```

---

The above approach would give number of rows having that keyword in it. If you want to find total number of times a particular keyword occurs in all the statements we can use `str_count` from `stringr`

```
sapply(keywords, function(x) sum(stringr::str_count(df$strings, x)))
```

OR split the strings into words and count number of occurrences

```
sapply(keywords, function(x) sum(grepl(x, unlist(strsplit(df$strings, "\\s+")))))
```